# Apache spark window, chose previous last item based on some condition

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, apache-spark-dataset

I have an input data which has id, pid, pname, ppid which are id (can think it is time), pid (process id), pname (process name), ppid (parent process id) who created pid

```
+---+---+-----+----+
| id|pid|pname|ppid|
+---+---+-----+----+
|  1|  1|    5|  -1|
|  2|  1|    7|  -1|
|  3|  2|    9|   1|
|  4|  2|   11|   1|
|  5|  3|    5|   1|
|  6|  4|    7|   2|
|  7|  1|    9|   3|
+---+---+-----+----+
```

now need to find ppname (parent process name) which is the last pname (previous pnames) of following condition `previous.pid == current.ppid`

expected result for previous example:

```
+---+---+-----+----+------+
| id|pid|pname|ppid|ppname|
+---+---+-----+----+------+
|  1|  1|    5|  -1|    -1|
|  2|  1|    7|  -1|    -1| no item found above with pid=-1
|  3|  2|    9|   1|     7| last pid = 1(ppid) above, pname=7
|  4|  2|   11|   1|     7| 
|  5|  3|    5|   1|     7|
|  6|  4|    7|   2|    11| last pid = 2(ppid) above, pname=11 
|  7|  1|    9|   3|     5| last pid = 3(ppid) above, pname=5
+---+---+-----+----+------+
```

I can join by itself based on `pid==ppid` then take diff between ids and pick row with min positive difference maybe then join back again for the cases where we didn't find any positive diffs (-1 case).

But I am thinking it is almost like a cross join, which I might not afford since I have 100M rows.

Comment: What would be the answer for rows with id=3,4,5 if rows with id=1 and id=2 of initial data are exchanged? Would the ppname change? Does pname with a particular pid always increase?

Comment: you can think of pname is a string (not int), if the rows change but id=1 and id=2 keeps values then (3,4,5) will not change, we are looking for `id` which is closest one to the current ones `id` and current `ppid` should be same to `pid` of the previous item